# Cut, drawn and quartered

Tags: riddle, word

> I can be cut, drawn and quartered
>
> But was never alive
>
> I don’t play fair
>
> But I stay alone and take my time.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be-

> Pack of Cards , the cards are, cut , drawn, quartered (i.e. divided among 4 players). You don't play fair in card games, you often bluff. (Cheat is also the name of a card game), also staying alone refers to another card game called solitare and you have to be patient in a card game hence the line- take some time.

Comment: How does that fit "I stay alone" part?

Comment: Well, that's half of the riddle, and the answer's right. If you wanted to know what the other lines meant it was rot13(qbag cynl snve vf purng, nybar vf fbyvgnver, naq gnxvat gvzr vf cngvrapr gurl'er nyy pneq tnzrf)

Comment: An interpretation I'd take on quartered would be the 4 suits in the deck, each with an even number of cards, so each make up 1/4 of the whole